# Why wont the points variable display in my label?

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode, label

I want the Points number to appear on a label which I have called the score. It keeps coming up with errors. I have tried multiple different ways but every time it pulls an error. Can someone resolve this, please?

```
//VARIABLES
var currentQuestion = 0
var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0
var points:UInt32 = 0

//SCORE

@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!

//QUESTION
@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!


//BUTTON
@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject)
{
    if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
    {
        print("Right")
        points += 1
    }
    else
    {
        print("Wrong")
    }

    if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
    {
        newQuestion()
    }
    else
    {
        score.text = points
    }
}
```

Comment: The answers are.... valid. But **you** aren't telling us something. Namely, what is your error? (It's only an assumption on our part until you tell us.)

Comment: If you are getting an error then you need to tell your readers what that error is, and what line it's on. Otherwise we're guessing. Please learn how to ask a good question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a UILabel .text property (which is a String) to an Int. You need to make it a String first. Like this:

```
score.text = "\(points)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text` property of the `UILabel` is of type `String`, so you need to cast `points` to `String` before setting it to `score.text`. Replace:

```
score.text = points
```

With:

```
score.text = "\(points)"
```

Or

```
score.text = String(points)
```

As a side note, in Swift you can write your `if` statements like this:

```
if currentQuestion != questions.count {

}
```